# Cannot figure out how to manage MBProgressHUD and dispatch

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, dispatch, mbprogresshud

I'm implementing an iOS app and trying to do the following while uploading a photo to a server:

- Start upload process with Alamofire
- Display a progress indicator with MBProgressHUD
- When the upload is done, hide the progress indicator
- Depending on the server response, display a message (success or fail)
  then dismiss the view

And I'm not able to achieve that, especially about dismissing the view after displaying the response message for 2 seconds. Here is my code.
How would you proceed please?
Thanks.

```
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    var progressHUD: MBProgressHUD! = nil

    func sendToServer(image: UIImage, imageName: String) {

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(jpgImageData!, withName: "photos",fileName: fname, mimeType: mime)
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        },
                         to:url!)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):         
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.progressHUD.show(animated: true)
                        self.progressHUD.progress = (Float(progress.fractionCompleted))
                        self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true, afterDelay: 3)
                    })

                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                        if let result = response.result.value {
                            var message = String()
                            message = "200, OK"

                            self.progressHUD.label.text = message
                            self.progressHUD.show(animated: true)
                            self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true, afterDelay: 2)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        var message = String()
                        message = "Not 200, NOK"

                        self.progressHUD.label.text = message
                        self.progressHUD.show(animated: true)
                        self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true, afterDelay: 2)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                        })
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                var message = String()
                message = "Failure, NOK"

                self.progressHUD.label.text = message
                self.progressHUD.show(animated: true)
                self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true, afterDelay: 2)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is working great.
The last `DispatchQueue`, which dismisses the view, is not executed immediately bat after 2 seconds. Here is the code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                            }
```

I hope that helps.